# Creating multiple dataframes simultaneously based on different values in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to create multiple dataframes based on values in a column.

> ## sample data
>
> ```
> df
> Index Product ID Amount
> 200   Prod1   01 100
> 201   Prod1   01 150
> 202   Prod1   01 123
> 203   Prod1   01 123
> 204   Prod1   02 110
> 205   Prod1   02 175
> 206   Prod1   02 190
> 207   Prod2   03 120
> 208   Prod2   03 135
> 209   Prod2   03 150
> ```

I would like to add a column as Base for each ID. The value of Base is the first amount value in each ID.

```
>df1
Index Product ID Amount Base
200   Prod1   01 100    100
201   Prod1   01 150    100
202   Prod1   01 123    100
203   Prod1   01 123    100
204   Prod1   02 110    110
205   Prod1   02 175    110
206   Prod1   02 190    110
207   Prod2   03 120    120
208   Prod2   03 135    120
209   Prod2   03 150    120
```

I am thinking of subset the df by ID first. Just wondering if any way to do this?

Comment: If your df is sorted: `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(sset) within(sset, Base <- Amount[1])))`

Comment: Do you need the _first_ `Amount` value that appears or the _minimum_ `Amount` value to be put in `Base` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data.frame is called `dat`, here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, Base := Amount[1L], by=ID]
#    Index Product ID Amount Base
#  1:   200   Prod1  1    100  100
#  2:   201   Prod1  1    150  100
#  3:   202   Prod1  1    123  100
#  4:   203   Prod1  1    123  100
#  5:   204   Prod1  2    110  110
#  6:   205   Prod1  2    175  110
#  7:   206   Prod1  2    190  110
#  8:   207   Prod2  3    120  120
#  9:   208   Prod2  3    135  120
# 10:   209   Prod2  3    150  120
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create a list of data frames and then embed them into any environment you want using `list2env`

```
SubData <- lapply(unique(df$ID), function(x) cbind(df[df$ID == x, ], Base = df$Amount[df$ID == x][1]))


# [[1]]
#   Index Product ID Amount Base
# 1   200   Prod1  1    100  100
# 2   201   Prod1  1    150  100
# 3   202   Prod1  1    123  100
# 4   203   Prod1  1    123  100
# 
# [[2]]
#   Index Product ID Amount Base
# 5   204   Prod1  2    110  110
# 6   205   Prod1  2    175  110
# 7   206   Prod1  2    190  110
# 
# [[3]]
#    Index Product ID Amount Base
# 8    207   Prod2  3    120  120
# 9    208   Prod2  3    135  120
# 10   209   Prod2  3    150  120
```

Now give your data frames whatever names you want and use `list2env` in order to create them in the environment

```
names(SubData) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
list2env(SubData, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Now you have these datasets in the global enviroment, e.g.

```
df1
##   Index Product ID Amount Base
## 1   200   Prod1  1    100  100
## 2   201   Prod1  1    150  100
## 3   202   Prod1  1    123  100
## 4   203   Prod1  1    123  100
```

Comment: user3689870, see my edit re `list2env`, I think this would be the proper way to do this

Comment: user3689870, didn't you want multiple data frames?

Answer (score 4):

Using `ave`:

```
dat$Base <- ave(dat$Amount,dat$ID,FUN=min)

# Index Product ID Amount Base
# 1    200   Prod1  1    100  100
# 2    201   Prod1  1    150  100
# 3    202   Prod1  1    123  100
# 4    203   Prod1  1    123  100
# 5    204   Prod1  2    110  110
# 6    205   Prod1  2    175  110
# 7    206   Prod1  2    190  110
# 8    207   Prod2  3    120  120
# 9    208   Prod2  3    135  120
# 10   209   Prod2  3    150  120
```

### EDIT

In case you want the first value and the minium one:

```
dat$Base <- ave(dat$Amount,dat$ID,FUN=function(x)x[1])
```

Comment: I didn't downvote any of you, also wondered why (thought perhaps bc in @agstudy's answer you are using `min` and not the first value of `Amount`)?

Comment: @beginneR Maybe..I edit my answer to add first value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr` to create the `Base` column, but just to be clear, this does not yet create different data.frames (as indicated in your question).

```
require(dplyr)

df <- df %.% group_by(ID) %.% mutate(Base = first(Amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
  arrange(ID, Amount) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Base = Amount[1])
```

Comment: Nice one! I'm not sure if the sorting/arranging is necessary, since in the question the OP says "The value of Base is the first amount value in each ID", not the minimum value.

Comment: @beginneR Oops, you are right. Well I'll leave it anyway to show how easy sorting is with dplyr. :)

Comment: Can't find where `%>%` is documented. Any tips?

Comment: `%>%` is documented [here](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) (and originally [here](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) )